# Отключение и включение кнопки

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Изначально кнопка заблокирована

```
<div id="test">
    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="send" name="send">
    <button v-bind:disabled="isButtonDisabled"></button>
</div>
```

В js файле:

```
var send = new Vue({
el: '#test',
data: {
    isButtonDisabled: true,
    canSend: false,
    send: ''
},
watch: {
    send: function(){
      this.send.length >= 2 ? send.canSend = true : send.canSend = false;
    }
}
```

Пишу условие в кнопке для её разблокировки:

```
<button v-if="canSend === true ? isButtonDisabled = false : isButtonDisabled = true" v-bind:disabled="isButtonDisabled"></button>
```

При наступлении условия `canSend === true` кнопка просто пропадает, при наступлении `canSend === false` кнопка возвращается.
Что делать не знаю, документация Vue.js ответа не дала

Comment: подозреваю, что смысл `v-if` в задании условия наличия (видимости) элемента  на странице

Comment: И как мне тогда поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нюанс в том, что значение атрибута `disabled` не имеет значения :), важно его наличие (даже если он вообще без значения):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "button",
  data: {
    isButtonDisabled: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<button :disabled="isButtonDisabled">Click 1</button>
<button :disabled="!isButtonDisabled">Click 2</button>
```

```js
var send = new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  data: {
    isButtonDisabled: true,
    canSend: false,
    send: ''
  },
  watch: {
    send: function() {
      this.canSend = this.send.length >= 2;
      this.isButtonDisabled = !this.canSend;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <input type="text" v-model="send" name="send">
  <button :disabled="isButtonDisabled">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну а как мне сделать рабочим мой пример?) Если добавить ещё одну кнопку переключатель то всё работает <button v-on:click="isButtonDisabled = !isButtonDisabled">123</button> Но мне нужно работоспособное условие

Comment: @Алексей Пардон, что значит "Ваш пример"? У Вас есть пример? Я вижу только несколько обрывков кода в вопросе. Или это я должен сочинить пример?

Comment: Дополнил пример на скорую руку

Comment: Я очень сильно укоротил свой пример (много условий) и результат нужен именно через изменение isButtonDisabled. Те в конечном итоге должно выглядеть If(canSend === true && и тд && и тд ) {isButtonDisabled = false;} Но это не работает... Спасибо что хоть попытались помочь